# Getting error: function is not iterable. how can i solve it

Tags: python-3.x

need help in last section of code in order to make iterable.

```
 d = filter(lambda w : w%2 == 0, (map((lambda s:s*2), (lambda *b :[sum(j)/2 for j in zip(*b)]))))

 print(list(d(list_one,list_two)))





 d = filter(lambda w : w%2 == 0, (map((lambda s:s*2), (lambda *b :[sum(j)/2 for j in zip(*b)]))))
```

Type Error: 'function' object is not iterable.

i want to use filter, map and lambda altogether.just want to know what am i doing wrong in this 
    code.

Comment: What do you expect `map` over a lambda as second argument to do? It would be helpful if you could reduce your code to only the inner part and explain exactly what you want this part to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggling to unpack the nested brackets, but you seem to be trying to use both a list comprehension and lambda in the *b term. I think perhaps if you remove the `lambda *b:` completely it might do what you intended.

Right now you are using two lambdas which means you are passing two function objects to `map` whereas it expects a function and an iterable.